# how to accept multiple jsonarray in android

Tags: android, arrays

[image]

My Java Code is

```
{
                        JSONArray queries_arr = result.getJSONArray("queries");
                        JSONArray teacher_arr= result.getJSONArray("teacher");
//                      JSONArray Res_teacher = result.getJSONArray("respective_teacher");<br>
//                      System.out.println("---->"+Res_teacher);
                        init1(teacher_arr);<br>
                        init(queries_arr);<br>
                    //  init1(queries_arr);<br>
                    }
```

Comment: please help me out. how to get two Jsonarray of "queries" and "teacher" in my JSON output

Comment: provide a response example and tell what you want to extract from it

Comment: There are two extra close and open braces before 'teacher' array. that was server side error.

Comment: yes thank u @arun,, but i want t read teacher array which was out side the braces .. how to get

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int sp = json.indexOf("}{");
String json1 = json.substring(0,sp+1);
String json2 = xy.substring(sp+1);

JSONObject result1 = new JSONObject(json1);
JSONObject result2 = new JSONObject(json2);
JSONArray queries_arr = result1.getJSONArray("queries");
JSONArray teacher_arr= result2.getJSONArray("teacher");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Make different jsonobject** for getting different array from your response .

```
JSONObject jsonObjQuery = response.getjObj();
JSONObject jsonObjTeacher = response.getjObj();
```

Then,

```
JSONArray jsonQueryArray = new JSONArray(jsonObjQuery .getString("queries"));
JSONArray jsonTeacherArray = new JSONArray(jsonObjTeacher .getString("teacher"));
```